# .htaccess, <Directory />, Internal Server Error, 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am in htaccess file

```
<Index "">
<Files "*.php">
Order Reject, Allow
Reject All
</Files>
```

I give the `</Directory>` command but it gives an internal error.
Please help, why is this happening? I don't use WordPress, my website is on VDS.

```
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
<Files "*.php">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: The error is from apache or PHP? Based on question contents it sounds like apache, so PHP isn't relevant here.

Comment: Code to prevent PHP upload to the folder, but it gives a directory error

Comment: Which version of Apache are you using? 2.2 or 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** use the `Directory` directive in .htaccess.

When you check the documentation, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory, it says there:

> Context:  server config, virtual host

- and that means, this directive can be used in the main server configuration files, or within a `VirtualHost` container - but not in .htaccess.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context

Comment: So, how can I turn off the permission to load external shells on my site?

Comment: Put it into the server configuration; or put a .htaccess file without the `Directory` directive wrapping the rest, directly into the folder in which you want this to apply.